# Node.js sequelize model - can I define order of records on the model?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am newish to node, and can't figure out how to only return 1 record of a hasMany relationship, based on an attribute.

There's a `user`, `level`, and `levels_user` table. 
On `user`, I want to include 1 `levels_user` where `level_id` is highest.

Can I put a condition on this model file, something like:

`order_by: ['level_id', 'DESC']`

LevelsUsers Model

```
  'use strict';
  module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    let LevelsUsers = sequelize.define('LevelsUsers', {
        user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        level_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        created_at: DataTypes.DATE,
        updated_at: DataTypes.DATE,
    },{
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        schema: "public",
        tableName: "levels_users"
    });


    return LevelsUsers;
};
```

Users model association:

```
    Users.hasMany(models.LevelsUsers, {
        as: 'levels_users',
        targetKey: 'id',
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
    });
```

This is my call:

```
users.getProfileByUserId = (req, res) => {
    models.Users.findOne({
      where: {id: req.params.userid},
      include: [
        {
          model: models.LevelsUsers,
          as: 'levels_users',
          limit: 1,
        }
      ]
      order: []
   }).then(user ....
```

I tried adding:

```
     `order: [
        [ models.LevelsUsers , 'level_id', 'DESC']
      ]`
```

Did not work and I think it's evaluated after `limit: 1` anyways.

Can I put `order_by` on the model, to return highest to lowest by `level_id` each time? If not, what's a better way to accomplish returning only the highest `levels_users` record where `level_id` is highest?

Answer (score 0):

The hasMany property is more suited when you want to include all the levels in the user object. In your case, I would advise to just pull the user without it's levels, and then do a second request to pull the higher level linked to that user by querying directly the LevelsUsers model :

```js
models.LevelsUsers.findAll({
  where: {
    user_id: user.id,
  },
  order: ['level_id', 'DESC'],
  limit: 1,
});
```

Comment: Hi - thanks! I will have other calls in the future to pull all of a users LevelsUser (and I can think of other use cases with other tables). Is it not possible to require a model to always order the records by an attribute when called? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well i reading over the documentation of `sequelize` for working with ordering and limit inside the includes tag.

Update query

```
users.getProfileByUserId = (req, res) => {
    models.Users.findOne({
      where: {id: req.params.userid},
      include: [
        {
          model: models.LevelsUsers,
          as: 'levels_users',
          order: [
            [ { model: models.LevelsUsers }, 'level_id', 'DESC']
          ],
          limit: 1,
        }
      ]
   }).then(user ....
```

For references go over the following links - https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4553#issuecomment-341261957